# clojure: how to pick up one item with the most high value from a map

Tags: clojure

I have the following map. And give a parameter of sex, need to pickup the user without the most money for that sex. How to do it?

```
{:user1 {:money 400 :sex :male}
:user2 {:money 300 :sex :female}
:user3 {:money 200 :sex :male}
}
```

Comment: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce

Comment: You need to get the user *without* the most money for a given sex, or *with* the most money for a given sex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you could write it (thanks to @Lee for the idea of using `max-key`!):

```
(defn richest [sex users]
  (apply max-key (comp :money val) (filter (comp #{sex} :sex val) users)))
```

So, you first filter out all the users that don't fit your criterion. For each entry in `users`, you get the `val` of that entry, then get the value of `:sex` under that, then check whether that result is contained in the one-element set containing `sex`.

Then, once you've filtered out the users you don't want, you look through the resulting sequence of entries. For each entry, you again get the `val` of the entry, then get the value of `:money` under that, and finally return the item that gave the highest result for that query.

Examples:

```
(def users {:user1 {:money 400 :sex :male}
            :user2 {:money 300 :sex :female}
            :user3 {:money 200 :sex :male}})

(richest :male users)
;=> [:user1 {:money 400, :sex :male}]

(richest :female users)
;=> [:user2 {:money 300, :sex :female}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `max-key`:

```
(defn richest-by-sex [users s]
  (apply max-key (comp :money second) (filter (fn [[n v]] (= s (:sex v))) users)))
```